# "Do not keep activities " uncheck from code

Tags: android

Is there any way to uncheck the option "Do not keep activities " from developer settings in the code of my application? I want to check the status and uncheck this option for my application. Is this possible?

Comment: no it is not. The only thing you can do from the application is to start the settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not rely on that setting, activities can be destroyed even if that setting is turned off (for instance, if the device is running low on memory).Also, you can not disable / enable the setting programatically.

You can, however, check if the setting is turned on, with this code:

```
boolean enabled;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
    enabled = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ALWAYS_FINISH_ACTIVITIES, 0) == 1;
} else {
    enabled = Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.ALWAYS_FINISH_ACTIVITIES, 0) == 1;
}
```

Comment: Also on API >= 17 you cannot change this value as it is made part of `Settings.System`.

Comment: That's right, but i dont think it would work even on lower apis, where it's still in `Settings.Global`. You could change it, but it wouldnt do anything...

Comment: I think your if clause should be reversed.